# pac script from OSX/Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

How do I execute a PAC script from a Cocoa desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [CFNetworkCopyProxiesForAutoConfigurationScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFProxySupport/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007846-CH6-DontLinkElementID_6) which is available in Mac OS X v10.5 and later.

Comment: Is requires the script itself and I have a URL for the script. Do I have to go get it myself using HTTP or something or is there a similar function that receives a URL to a PAC script as opposed to the script itself?